# Pagar el pato. ¿De dónde salió esta expresión?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, coloquialismos

Mis mayores han utilizado por años la expresión **"Pagar el pato"** que se aplica a cuando alguien paga las consecuencias de un acto que no cometió.

Vi alguna teoría de origen religioso donde se decía que en España se burlaban de los judíos diciéndoles que iban a "pagar el pacto" que tenían con Dios y que "pacto" derivó en "pato", pero esa teoría poco me convence.

¿Existe alguna teoría más consistente sobre el origen de "Pagar el pato"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En la [**Fundación Lengua Española**](https://www.fundacionlengua.com/es/pagar-pato/art/151/) señalan:

> Según el Diccionario significa "padecer o llevar un castigo no merecido o que ha merecido otro". Seijas Patiño, en su Comentario al ‘Cuento de cuentos· de Quevedo, lo define como "llevar alguno el castigo que merece otro; de origen vulgar y tomado acaso de algún juego o diversión".
>
> Este modismo fue utilizado contra los judíos. En la Biblia Castellana de Casiodoro Reina, se explica así su origen: "Como los vocablos Tora y Pacto, usados por los judíos españoles, el primero por la Ley y el segundo por el concierto de Dios, por los cuales los españoles les acusaban de que tenían una Tora o becerra pintada en su sinagoga, que adoraban; y del Pacto sacaron por refrán: Aquí pagaréis el pato".
>
> **Iribarren, José Mª**; El porqué de los dichos. Gobierno de Navarra. Departamento de Educación, Cultura, Deporte y Juventud. Novena edición. Octubre 1996, pág. 25.

Por otro lado, [**Alfred López**](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-surge-la-expresion-pagar-el-pato/) da una interpretación ligeramente distinta al mismo origen:

> En la Biblia Castellana de Casiodoro Reina aparece recogida dicha cita: «Como los vocablos Torá y Pacto, usados por los judíos españoles, el primero por la Ley y el segundo por el concierto de Dios, por los cuales los españoles les levantaban (les acusaban a los judíos) que tenían una Tora o becerra pintada en su sinagoga, que adoraban; y del Pacto, sacaron por refrán “aquí pagaréis el pato”».
>
> **Generalizando podríamos decir que cualquier pacto entro dos partes acaba implicando que una tercera sufra las consecuencias negativas y pague el pacto. La palabra pacto acabó derivando en pato y eliminando toda connotación religiosa a la expresión hoy en día.**

Comment: Bueno, parece que la explicación que no me convence del todo es la única que hay. Esperaré un par de días para marcarla como respuesta aceptada. Gracias.

Comment: @DGaleano, sorry for writing in English (I understand Spanish, but can't write properly). I found another hypothesis, a medieval anecdote (before 1459) where a husband pays for a goose that his wife had already paid for (by sleeping with the seller). You can see the detais [here (Portuguese languase SE](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8877/qual-a-origem-da-express%c3%a3o-pagar-o-pato/8886#8886); it's in Portuguese (we say *pagar o pato*), I'll add an English translation if you like.

Comment: About the hypothesis you mention. I read the relevant bit of Casiodoro Reina's bible, and he does not say anything about *pagar el pacto*, only that from the Jew's claim that they had a "pacto", the Spanish "sacaron por refran contraellos, Aqui pagareis el pato". It is not even clear to me (maybe it is to you...) that he is claiming this is the origin *pagar el pato*; could he simply mean that the Spanish used an already existing phrase to mock the Jews? *Pagar el pato* (as opposed to *pagareis*...) was already in use in Casiodoro's lifetime.